# Error installing JDBC drivers in Maven

Tags: java, eclipse, oracle, maven, jdbc

I have imported a project in eclipse (Mars) and I have, in my pom.xml, file the following error: "Missing artifact com.oracle:ojdbc7:jar:12.1.0.1"

This is the code:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
    <version>12.1.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

I have downloaded the ojdbc7.jar from Oracle, and i tried to install it using the following command:

mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=com.oracle -DartifactId=ojdbc7 -Dversion=12.1.0.1 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=ojdbc7.jar -DgeneratePom=true

The problem is that i have an output saying:

[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[ERROR] Error resolving version for plugin 'com.oracle:ojdbc7' from the repositories 
[local (PATH.m2\repository), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)]: Plugin not found in any plugin repository -> [Help 1]

Comment: can you post a little bit more of your `pom.xml`, the part around what you already posted. The error message is talking about a "plugin", that's odd

Answer (score 0):

(a) While Installing the ojdbc7.jar, your -Dfile value should be related to the path where you have the downloaded ojdbc7.jar file. 
(b) First do the install and them add the dependency in pom.xml

mvn install:install-file \
      -Dfile=/opt/test/12101/ojdbc7.jar \
      -DgroupId=com.oracle \
      -DartifactId=ojdbc7 \
      -Dversion=12.1.0.1 \
      -Dpackaging=jar \
      -DgeneratePom=true